# How to reduce loud noises in Haier air conditioning/heat unit?

Tags: hvac, noise

This new unit rumbles loudly when the heat comes on. Haier technicians attempted to fix by limiting the settings/functionaities I can use. They also added a "muffler" between the outside and inside units which is only partially successful and has further limited functionality (e.g. I can't use "Quiet" mode anymore. It just produces ongoing rumbling and clattering.) Sometimes normal heat functions make loud noises. I am constantly trying to adjust the settings to stop the noise. Have others had this experience with Haier? What can be done? Is this just an inherently sub-standard product which can't be fixed?

Comment: Unless they had warned you about it before installation, get them to take it away.

Answer (score 1):

I would not accept that a new unit needs to be modified to reduce functions for the purpose of noise abatement. Any loud rumble is not normal for any AC unit.  The most likely culprit is the fan.  It may be unbalanced or simply not anchored properly or the fan assembly may be touching another component that is magnifying the sound.

If the service techs cannot get the unit to run with a reasonable noise level, ask for a new unit that performs all the functions that you paid for and does so with reasonable sound quality.

Comment: Agree 100% - this is a warranty claim situation!